# It is possible to post data with jsonp in Angular 5 without query string?

Tags: angular, cors, http-post, jsonp

I am doing a CORS webservice call and want to use Angular 5's `jsonp()` method. But I cannot find a way to post my screen values as body parameter. The only way I see is by passing values as query string which I dont want to use becaues my screen data is big.

I dont have control over the web service, so I cannot ask them to set anything like this on the server side:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

Here is my JSONP code in Angular 5:

```
let body = JSON.stringify({ Key1: Value1, Key2 : Value2 });
const headers = new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

return this.http.jsonp(this.serviceUrlProxy, "JSONCallBack" )
```

So, is it even possible to send data to the webservice when using Angular 5's `jsonp()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSONP is GET request, it isn't supposed to have body, all data should be sent as query string.

So no, it's not possible.

In case of CORS problems alternative solutions such as CORS proxy may be used.

Comment: Thanks, let me check CORS proxy.